# Orbeon build from source does not work

Tags: orbeon

I am trying to build the project from the source in GitHub from the branch '2017.1-ce' and when I built the project I obtained a zip file with WARs. I deployed orbeon.war to tomcat 8.5.20. After deployment, the main page /orbeon/home looks broken(without some styles) and form builder and form runner does not work at all. When I downloaded your artifacts from orbeon.com/download with the same version I deployed on the same Tomcat container and it works correctly.
I am building using Windows 10. Could you please help me.

Comment: I found that size of artifact from my build has less size that I downloaded directly from the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing, building Orbeon Forms is only supported on macOS and Linux, as those are the platform currently used by Orbeon Forms developers and Continuous Integration. It should certainly be possible to build Orbeon Forms on Windows as well, but the issue you mentioned hasn't been tackled yet. So, I'd recommend you either:

- Investigate the issue with building on Windows, and when you find a solution submit a pull request.
- Use Docker for Windows (or similar) so you can run Linux and still build locally on Windows.